# How do I write a ScriptFilter in log4j2.xml?

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I am having some trouble writing the `ScriptFilter` as the resources for this on the Internet/StackOverflow are quite limited. I hope someone from the community will be able to guide me :)

I want to filter out certain logs depending on the environment the application has been deployed in. We configure the environment by setting the `SPRING_ARGS_PORT` in the Bash script in a Jenkins build job, as follows:

```bash
export SPRING_ARGS_PORT="--server.port=$PORT --env=dev1"
```

In the above Bash script, we deployed the application to the `dev1` environment.

The application `jar` file is then run with `java -jar application.jar --SPRING_ARGS_PORT=$SPRING_ARGS_PORT`.

The `log4j2.xml` file I've written as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="OFF">


<Console name="prodOutput" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="..."/>
        <Filters>
            <ScriptFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
            <Script name="checkLoggerOutType" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
                var value = "${env:SPRING_ARGS_PORT}";
                var envIndex = value.indexOf("--env=");
                if (envIndex >= 0 && value.substring(envIndex + "--env=".length) == "dev1") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            ]]></Script>
        </ScriptFilter>
        </Filters>
</Console>


</configuration>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to filter out logs when the environment is "dev1" (as defined in `SPRING_ARGS_PORT`), but it doesn't seem to work as I'm still seeing the logs

Would anyone be able to help point out what I'm doing wrong or missing? Thank you :)

The StackOverflow posts I referenced for the syntax of writing a `ScriptFilter` were the following:

- [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69323224/15781733)
- [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48169152/15781733)

I'm guessing I got the syntax right by comparing against these 2 posts, perhaps my logic is wrong or I'm missing something else?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the `JavaScript` code should be written as follows:

```
<Script name="checkLoggerOutType" language="JavaScript"><![CDATA[
    var value = "${env:SPRING_ARGS_PORT}";
    var envIndex = value.indexOf("--env=");
    if (envIndex >= 0 && value.substring(envIndex + "--env=".length) == "dev1") {
        true;
    } else {
        false;
    }
]]></Script>
```

Note the difference is that the boolean values should not be returned, they should be written plainly as such.

This format was clearly present in the first StackOverflow post I referenced, but I had missed that small detail.

Hope this is helpful to anyone who might be looking into using the `ScriptFilter` for log4j